# Intellij Java Maven Localhost:8080 wont excecute method in controller

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm working on a Java Maven webbased application.
Although the applicatie builds and runs without error, it won't seem to excecute any of the methods I specify in the url. I try to call them using the url: Localhost:8080\login and Localhost:8080\register

My question: **Am I missing something? If so, what and how do I fix this**?

```
import Models.Users;
import Services.iUserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    iUserService IUserService;

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public Users GetUsername(String em, String pw)
    {
        return IUserService.GetUsername(em, pw);
    }

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public boolean RegisterNewUser(String un, String em, String pw, String pn) //username, email, password, phonenumber
    {
        return IUserService.RegisterNewUser(un, em, pw, pn);
    }

}`
```

Comment: And how are you starting the application and what are you calling the URLs with and what do you expect that doesn't happen?

Comment: Well, that's actually it. I press run and put the Url in the browser and it should work, no?

Comment: You press run what? Run maven build (will it laumch the app no it won't). So again what do you exactly do.

Comment: I use Intellij with Springboot 2.2.6 Release configuration

Comment: Do you also have a class annotated with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, with a main method to run. You should `run` this main method. Otherwise no tomcat will boot up.

Comment: That isn't answering my question, **what** are you running. A main method, a maven build, tests. **what** not how, **what** are you running.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try use in your url "/", not "\"

`localhost:8080/register`

instead of

`Localhost:8080\register`

Check if your Tomcat started properly and using port 8080

**@Edit:**

```
@Autowired
    iUserService IUserService;
```

What about this part of the code ? You have to paste more details in your question.

Comment: I'm using the MVC Repository pattern in this project. The Service is a class for repeated general code. Also, The Tomcat is using port 8080

Comment: Describe step by step how are you starting application.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your application is actually running on port 8080.
You can also define another port in your applicaiton.yaml file:

```
server:
  port: 8081
```